# How to double a value of private int type field?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, constructor, super

This is the code of method `takeDamage` in the class `Enemy` which is a superclass of class `Vampire`.

```
public void takeDamage(int damage) {
    int remainingHitPoints = hitPoints - damage;

    if (remainingHitPoints > 0) {
        setHitPoints(remainingHitPoints);
        System.out.println(name + " took " + damage + " damage and have " + remainingHitPoints + " HitPoint left" + "\n------------------------------------" );
    } else {
        this.lives = this.lives - 1;
        System.out.println(name + " took " + damage + " damage" + "\n------------------------------------" + "\n" + name +" lost a life" + "\n------------------------------------");

        if (lives > 0) {
            System.out.println(name + " revived" + "\n------------------------------------");
            setHitPoints(remainingHitPoints + damage);
        } else {
            System.out.println(name + " is dead now RIP" + "\n------------------------------------");
            setHitPoints(0);
        }
    }
}
```

In the class `Vampire` I override the method `takeDamge`:

```
public void takeDamage(int damage) {
    int inflictedDamage = damage/2;
    int doubleHitPoints = getHitPoints()*2;
    int remainingHitPoints = getHitPoints() - inflictedDamage;
    int remainingLives = getLives() - 1;

    if (remainingHitPoints > 0) {
        setHitPoints(remainingHitPoints);
        System.out.println(getName() + " took " + inflictedDamage + " damage(Vampire takes inflicted damage) and has " + remainingHitPoints + " HitPoint left" + "\n------------------------------------" );
    } else {
        setLives(remainingLives);
        System.out.println(getName() + " took " + inflictedDamage + " damage(Vampire takes inflicted damage)" + "\n------------------------------------" + "\n" + getName() +" lost a life" + "\n------------------------------------");

        if (remainingLives > 0) {
            System.out.println(getName() + " revived and even got stronger!" + "\n------------------------------------");
            setHitPoints(doubleHitPoints);
        } else {
            System.out.println(getName() + " is dead now RIP" + "\n------------------------------------");
            setHitPoints(0);
        }
    }
}
```

**What I intend to do is double the object's `hitPoints` which is originally set by the constructor.**

When a `Vampire` object takes enough damage to die (in other words, when it loses its life), this method successfully doubles the object's `hitPoints`.

The problem happens (if I diagnosed right) when the `Vampire` object takes not enough damage to die.

`setHitPoints(remainingHitpoints);` gets executed and when the `Vampire` object takes enough damage to die, it doubles the object's `remainingHitPoints` not an original `hitPoints`.

I would like to fix this issue.

The `hitPoints` field has been declared as private inside the `Enemy` class so if I understood well the only way to modify the value of this field is by using `getHitPoint` method (getter) inside the `Enemy` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need some place where the original hit points are stored.

If your `Enemy` class doesn't provide this information and you only need it in the `Vampire` class you could change the `Vampire` class along these lines:

```
public class Vampire extends Enemy {

    private int originalHitPoints;

    public Vampire() {
        // ...
        originalHitPoints = getHitPoints();
    }

    public void takeDamage(int damage) {
        // ...

        if (remainingLives > 0) {
            System.out.println(getName() + " revived and even got stronger!" + "\n------------------------------------");
            setHitPoints(originalHitPoints * 2);
        }

        // ...
    }
}
```

If you want to double the hit points every time the Vampire dies you could change the code of `takeDamage()` like this:

```
    public void takeDamage(int damage) {
        // ...

        if (remainingLives > 0) {
            System.out.println(getName() + " revived and even got stronger!" + "\n------------------------------------");
            originalHitPointes *= 2; // double the hit points
            setHitPoints(originalHitPoints);
        }

        // ...
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I applied your advice into my code and indeed it works. I'm sorry to bother you again, Still my code doesn't function fully in my intended way. Furthermore, I would like to double the originalHitPoints each time till lives variable equals 0.  I tried to put for loops inside, but I didn't succeed. 
Could you please help ?

Comment: @JavaLearner I've added code on how you can double the original hit points every time the vampire dies.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: @JavaLearner if this answer worked then please mark it as "accepted"